# How to keep backward compatibility of UTF-8 on Android 9?

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, android-9.0-pie

one of the behavior changes introduced in Android 9 is more strict [UTF-8 decoder](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#decoder). If we have an array of bytes that are not correct UTF-8 string (for example random bytes or some binary data) and try to create a string out of it:

```java
return new String(bytes)
```

the Android will pick UTF-8 as preferred encoding (which is fine) but return a slightly different result on Android 9 than on older versions of Android.

I know that transforming random bytes into UTF-8 String doesn't sound like a good idea in a first place, but I need a backward compatibility for now.

**Is there an option to get exactly the same String result on all Android versions?**

Edit:

Steps to reproduce:

```java
    byte[] bytes =  new byte[]{25, 17, 113, 18, 62, 121, -6, -71, 45, -126, -113, 122, 58, 49, -30, -53, -66, -7, 0, -41};
    char[] password = new String(bytes).toCharArray();
    byte[] passKey = PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS12PasswordToBytes(password);
    Log.d("TEST", "Bytes: ".concat(Arrays.toString(passKey)));
```

Output for Android <9.0:

```
[0, 25, 0, 17, 0, 113, 0, 18, 0, 62, 0, 121, -1, -3, 0, 45, -1, -3, -1, -3, 0, 122, 0, 58, 0, 49, -1, -3, 2, -2, -1, -3, 0, 0, -1, -3, 0, 0]
```

Output for Android 9.0:

```
[0, 25, 0, 17, 0, 113, 0, 18, 0, 62, 0, 121, -1, -3, -1, -3, 0, 45, -1, -3, -1, -3, 0, 122, 0, 58, 0, 49, -1, -3, 2, -2, -1, -3, 0, 0, -1, -3, 0, 0]
```

Comment: A better idea is to convert binary data to base64 string which is guaranteed to be the same on any platform, not limited to Android.

Comment: I know that. There are many better options than UTF-8, but I'm looking for a backward compatible solution.

Comment: Do not upgrade to Android 9 target. Upgrading and having "backward compatible" solution is the start of having a huge mess (and bugs, and "features"). This is  good moment to correct your program (and allowing a transition period).

Comment: This happens on all Android 9 devices regarless of the targetSDK or compileSDK versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code, which was ported from the UTF-8 decoder of previous Android versions.

```
private static final char REPLACEMENT_CHAR = (char) 0xfffd;

public static char[] byteArrayToCharArray(byte[] data) {
    char[] value;
    final int offset = 0;
    final int byteCount = data.length;

    char[] v = new char[byteCount];
    int idx = offset;
    int last = offset + byteCount;
    int s = 0;
    outer:
    while (idx < last) {
        byte b0 = data[idx++];
        if ((b0 & 0x80) == 0) {
            // 0xxxxxxx
            // Range:  U-00000000 - U-0000007F
            int val = b0 & 0xff;
            v[s++] = (char) val;
        } else if (((b0 & 0xe0) == 0xc0) || ((b0 & 0xf0) == 0xe0) ||
                ((b0 & 0xf8) == 0xf0) || ((b0 & 0xfc) == 0xf8) || ((b0 & 0xfe) == 0xfc)) {
            int utfCount = 1;
            if ((b0 & 0xf0) == 0xe0) utfCount = 2;
            else if ((b0 & 0xf8) == 0xf0) utfCount = 3;
            else if ((b0 & 0xfc) == 0xf8) utfCount = 4;
            else if ((b0 & 0xfe) == 0xfc) utfCount = 5;
            // 110xxxxx (10xxxxxx)+
            // Range:  U-00000080 - U-000007FF (count == 1)
            // Range:  U-00000800 - U-0000FFFF (count == 2)
            // Range:  U-00010000 - U-001FFFFF (count == 3)
            // Range:  U-00200000 - U-03FFFFFF (count == 4)
            // Range:  U-04000000 - U-7FFFFFFF (count == 5)
            if (idx + utfCount > last) {
                v[s++] = REPLACEMENT_CHAR;
                continue;
            }
            // Extract usable bits from b0
            int val = b0 & (0x1f >> (utfCount - 1));
            for (int i = 0; i < utfCount; ++i) {
                byte b = data[idx++];
                if ((b & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
                    v[s++] = REPLACEMENT_CHAR;
                    idx--; // Put the input char back
                    continue outer;
                }
                // Push new bits in from the right side
                val <<= 6;
                val |= b & 0x3f;
            }
            // Note: Java allows overlong char
            // specifications To disallow, check that val
            // is greater than or equal to the minimum
            // value for each count:
            //
            // count    min value
            // -----   ----------
            //   1           0x80
            //   2          0x800
            //   3        0x10000
            //   4       0x200000
            //   5      0x4000000
            // Allow surrogate values (0xD800 - 0xDFFF) to
            // be specified using 3-byte UTF values only
            if ((utfCount != 2) && (val >= 0xD800) && (val <= 0xDFFF)) {
                v[s++] = REPLACEMENT_CHAR;
                continue;
            }
            // Reject chars greater than the Unicode maximum of U+10FFFF.
            if (val > 0x10FFFF) {
                v[s++] = REPLACEMENT_CHAR;
                continue;
            }
            // Encode chars from U+10000 up as surrogate pairs
            if (val < 0x10000) {
                v[s++] = (char) val;
            } else {
                int x = val & 0xffff;
                int u = (val >> 16) & 0x1f;
                int w = (u - 1) & 0xffff;
                int hi = 0xd800 | (w << 6) | (x >> 10);
                int lo = 0xdc00 | (x & 0x3ff);
                v[s++] = (char) hi;
                v[s++] = (char) lo;
            }
        } else {
            // Illegal values 0x8*, 0x9*, 0xa*, 0xb*, 0xfd-0xff
            v[s++] = REPLACEMENT_CHAR;
        }
    }
    if (s == byteCount) {
        // We guessed right, so we can use our temporary array as-is.
        value = v;
    } else {
        // Our temporary array was too big, so reallocate and copy.
        value = new char[s];
        System.arraycopy(v, 0, value, 0, s);
    }
    return value;
}
```

I've unit tested this by creating a random array of 20 bytes, and comparing to the original `new String(bytes).toCharArray()` implementation on previous Android version, and then repeated this a million times. I did not see any differences on multiple older Android versions.

The original source code is from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a7752f4d22097346dd7849b92b9f36d0a0a7a8f3/libdvm/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java#245
To simplify it, I removed the part which deals with non-UTF8 charsets, if you use `new String()`, then UTF-8 is the default charset which is used, so you should be fine.

This code will get you backward compatibility as you wanted. But as other people will suggest you, I advise to look for a simpler solution if possible, which is not dependent on Android versions (or other components, which are out of your control)

Comment: I've already solved my issue using pretty much the same code snippet taken from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/libart/src/main/java/java/lang/StringFactory.java#79 but will accept your answer for future readers :)